# php script to run bash script which runs scrapy crawler

Tags: php, html, bash, scrapy

I have a form in html page that has action to run php file. The php file has to run a bash function command which in turn runs a scrapy spider. Since I have the scrapy spider located outside var/www/, I have added a function in .bashrc to run the bash command ($ startscript) from anywhere. When I run it on the terminal from var/www folder or anywhere it works as expected but when I do it in php file it does not work. I am not sure if its because of php file permission, scrapy proprieties or something else.

Any suggestions?

.php file:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('startscript');
echo $output;
?>
```

.bashrc file:

```
function startscript
{
   cd /home/pi/IndeedCoUkCrawl
   ./BotScrapy.sh
}
```

Comment: are you sure that php's using bash for its shell_exec?

Comment: yes, I tested with $ ls and it works.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can try:

- put the absolute path of the startscript in shell_exec and see if it works.
- try running with error_reporting(E_ALL) and see if this give any error/notice
- check if your webserver has permissions to run the file. Try putting the file into the same group as the webserver runs in.